# Changing heap size in weka ERROR

Tags: weka

When i run the command

java -Xmx2g -classpath $CLASSPATH:weka.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser

I get the error

---Registering Weka Editors---
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?

How to fix this . I need to load a file in weka which has more than 1000 attributes .

Answer (score 0):

The error says nothing about the heap size, it says you are missing a database driver. If don't need database access, you should be fine. Does the GUI open up? If yes, you can ignore the error messages.